# How to include required files in Istanbul that are not in same directory as test case?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, istanbul

I'm trying to do something simple, but it's not working.. I must be doing something dumb.

I am using Istanbul with Mocha for code coverage + unit testing.

In the code being tested, it is using functions from modules which are being `require`'d, and I want those imported modules to be included in the code coverage - but it's not.

I am explicitly including a library from a `require` with a full path to it (it is not the same dir as where the test case resides)

```
var d = require(srcroot + '/scripting/wf_daemon/daemon_lib');
```

And then later, the test case is making a call to a function in that module `startWorkFlow`.

```
d.startWorkflow(workflow, function (msg) { // do something })
```

However, Istanbul does not go into the referenced function `startWorkFlow`, it only gives me coverage for the test file.

What I need is code coverage to extend into all functions from the modules `require`'d by the test case.

I am calling Istanbul like this:

```
istanbul cover --include-all-source --dir C:\Build\buildarea --print none "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\mocha/bin/_mocha" -- --reporter mocha-teamcity-reporter ./test.js
```

Is there any way to get Istanbul to instrument the files which are not in the directory (or subdirectories) where the test case resides? What simple mistake am I making?

Cheers!

Comment: It's sort of late for me so I'm probably wrong, but what if you pass the `--preload-sources` as a parameter to the `cover` command?

Comment: Also , shouldn't it be `--include-all-sources` (note the 's' suffix) , and shouldn't that be before the `cover` command (ie `istanbul --include-all-sources cover --preload-sources ...`

Comment: thanks - I was missing an "s".. the `--preload-sources` is deprecated I discovered (thought that might be it!), it's the `--include-all-sources` command now. However, it didn't work.. still doesn't include my libraries.. :(